# JS variables and css properties

Tags: javascript, css, value-of-css-property

If I put a css property in JS variable, and change the variable value, does the property change?

And a little subquestion: what's difference between let and var, and what should I use?

For example:

```
    let property = document.getElementById("el").style.display;
//  variable's content changed
    property = "block";
//  will the #el's display property change?
```

Comment: Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    let property = document.getElementById("el").style.display;
//  variable's content changed
    property = "block";
//  will the #el's display property change?
```

No . What is changing is the Javascript variable called property. First of all it takes on the value of the style.display of the element #el and then it is given the value of another string which is 'block'

It is possible to set a property of el but on the 'left hand side' you need to tell JS that is what you want it to do:

```
document.getElementById("el").style.display = "block";
```